# Deserializing a given file in java

Tags: java, eclipse

My teacher has given us a serialized file along with several classes and asked us to create a program to deserialize the file into an ArrayList. The file that the serialized information is located in is "c:/temp/HW2.ser".

```
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("c:/temp/HW2.ser");
System.out.println( fileIn );


ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
ArrayList<GeometricObject> list = (ArrayList<GeometricObject>)objIn.readObject();
objIn.close();
fileIn.close();

System.out.println( list );
```

I keep getting an error saying that the ObjectInputStream is an unknown source and I'm not sure what step I am missing. I think what I am missing is an objOut and a writeObject, but I can't figure out how to implement those without altering the file my teacher gave us. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you post exact message error/stackt race you are getting?

Comment: The actual error message and stack trace emitted would be useful.  In any case, you do not need to `writeObject()`; your instructor gave you a file that (he claims) already contains one or more serialized objects.

Comment: Since you seems new on Stack Overflow you may not know that to add more informations to your post you can simply use [[edit]] option below it.

Comment: Maybe also your teacher is using Java8 to create data and you are using Java5 ?  Ensure you are using the same of newer VM.  One would hope the format is guarded against this and a useful detection and exception is generated.

Comment: (Unknown Source) is commonly printed in exception reports when the VM does not know the source file and line number information.  This is not really the issue you need to fix.  Ensure you run your project with JDK (not JRE) and also build with debugging enabled, this will provide better quality stack traces.

Comment: Try checking if `fileIn.exists()` and `fileIn.isFile()`. You might have the path wrong or formatted incorrectly. For example, it might need to be `"C:\\temp\\HW2.ser"` (note: `"\\"` in a Java string is the escape character for `"\"`).